# DRF should create pagination class for different page_size?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I know I can create a pagination class and set `page_size` to control how big the page is.

Should I create a new pagination class for all possible `page_size` I need?

Is there a way to overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, it seems you need to create a class for each page size, however I solved a similar issue using a factory:

```
def PaginationFactory(size):
    class CustomPagination(PageNumberPagination):
        page_size = size

    return CustomPagination
```

Then in views, you could use:

```
pagination_class = PaginationFactory(10)
```